# JavaScript form validation for first name, last name and email address is displaying nothing

Tags: javascript

I am just copying my code:

### HTML

```
<form id='test'>
Name *
    <input id="lname" type="text"><span id="wronglname" class="error">*This is a required field</span>
        Name *
    <input id="name" type="text"><span id="wrongname" class="error">*This is a required field</span>

Email*
    <input id="email" type="text"><span id="wrongemail" class="error">* Wrong Email Address</span>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

### Javascript

```
function ValidateForm() {

    var hasError = false;

    if (document.getElementById('lname').value == "") {
        document.getElementById('lwrongname').style.display = "inline";
        hasError = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('wrongname').style.display = "none";   
    }
        if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
        document.getElementById('wrongname').style.display = "inline";
        hasError = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('wrongname').style.display = "none";   
    }

    if (document.getElementById('email').value.search(/^[a-zA-Z]+([_\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/) == -1) {
        document.getElementById('wrongemail').style.display = "inline";
        hasError = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('wrongemail').style.display = "none";   
    }

    return !hasError;
}


document.getElementById('test').onsubmit = ValidateForm;
```

### CSS

```
.error {
    display:none;
    color:red;
}
```

I am getting no response at all, and whenever I check javascript console by chrome, it shows me also no error, I am not too sure what's wrong with my coding, can anyone help me out?

Comment: how are you calling the ValidateForm() function ..?

Comment: I assume the script is in `<script>` tags?

Comment: @Sudhir see `document.getElementById('test').onsubmit = ValidateForm;`

Comment: @failed.down <script src="test.js"></script> and l put it on the last line of the body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your mistake:

```
if (document.getElementById('lname').value == "") {
        document.getElementById('lwrongname').style.display = "inline";
        hasError = true;
    }
```

Notice `document.getElementById('lwrongname')`, should be `document.getElementById('wronglname')`.

Comment: I know how it is when a small, invisible mistake gives you a huge headache. The reason why the console was not showing anything is probably because the form was being posted before you could see the error (which should have been something like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`). Also, unsolicited advice: use triple equals.